# How to Display only the Datepart using Expression in SSRS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I need to  display only the `Datepart(6/26/2000)` in the report by neglecting `Time` in the Report in SSRS. already i'm fetching the that `datetime` from the Dataset output column `Startdate`

**Expression Used**:

```
=First(Fields!start_dte_display.Value, "Salesvalue")
```

SalesValue==>Dataset name

**Output i'm getting from above Expression** :

```
6/26/2000 12:00:00 AM
```

**My expected Output**:

```
6/26/2000
```

Kindly Help me with the output!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try FORMAT:

```
=Format(First(Fields!start_dte_display.Value, "Salesvalue"), "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Note: MM has to be in upper-case, mm will get you minutes!

Comment: The format should be `M/d/yyyy`, because the output with your format (`MM/dd/yyyy`) will give `06/26/2000` instead of `6/26/2000`

Comment: @SébastienSevrin - Thank you, i didn't see that. i always use 2 digits for month and day so i took it for granted ;)

Comment: And just another comment while on this post, if you want to have always the same output format regardless of the culture of the report, you can use the `ToString()` method instead and pass the invariant culture like this `=CDate(First(Fields!start_dte_display.Value, "Salesvalue")).ToString("M/d/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Text-box properties** to set the date format as you want to show on the report. Just you need to right click on the text-box and choose Text Box Properties. In the Text Box Properties window you can choose Number > Date and date sample as 1/31/2000 and click on the **Ok** button.

Another simple way to set the Text Box Format = **M/d/yyyy** in properties window.